# Svelte: input update does not reflect latest input value

Tags: svelte

can someone help me fix this?

I provide a link, check the console.

Notice how when a new value is selected, the console printed is of the previous value.
link: https://svelte.dev/repl/ffea9836cf514436aadf9adb86e350d5?version=3.48.0

**Code**

```html
<script>
    import {tick} from 'svelte';
    
    let tortilla = 'Plain';
    
    async function InputChange(e) {
        await tick();       
        console.log(tortilla)
    }
</script>

<input on:change={InputChange} name="Plain" id="Plain" type="radio" bind:group={tortilla}                   value="Plain">
<label for="Plain">Plain</label>    
<input on:change={InputChange} name="Whole wheat" id="Whole wheat" type="radio" bind:group=                 {tortilla} value="Whole wheat">
<label for="Whole wheat">Whole wheat</label>    
<input on:change={InputChange} name="Spinach" id="Spinach" type="radio" bind:group={tortilla}           value="Spinach">
<label for="Spinach">Spinach</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the `on:change` handler *after* the `bind:`.
This is described in the documentation:

> If you're using bind: directives together with on: directives, the order that they're defined in affects the value of the bound variable when the event handler is called.
>
> ```html
> <script>
>   let value = 'Hello World';
> </script>
>
> <input
>   on:input="{() => console.log('Old value:', value)}"
>   bind:value
>   on:input="{() => console.log('New value:', value)}"
> />
> ```

You also don't need the `await tick()`.